# Trying to display a timeline for certain cases within a dataframe, based on multiple columns' contents

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

any help or pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

The data I'm working with: a dataframe with column1 for person name, column2 for specific dates, and column3 for values associated with those dates. Each person has multiple rows corresponding with different dates and values for those dates.

My goal: Find a way to display a timeline for each individual person, which shows each date and its associated value.

What I've done so far: I've figured out how to sort the data using pandas so that all rows for each person are grouped together, then each entry for said person is sorted by date. I can print the values for each person, but I need to find a way to display it as an actual timeline or something similar to be able to visually see the length between entries. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is an example code that gives a dataframe similar to what I'm working with (mine is just much larger with different variable names):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Sarah', 'Sarah', 'Bob'],
                     'date': ['2018-01-13', '2018-04-09', '2018-10-24', '2015-05-15', '2015-09-25', '2020-04-28'], 
                     'case': ['meeting', 'hearing', 'lunch', 'meeting', 'dinner', 'meeting']})
```

Comment: Do you mean a graphical representation? I would suggest to use `matplotlib` or a similar library to plot the data. Also, please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use matplotlib whit a lineplot where x= date and y=value, use matplotlib.pyplot.text to display each name on the line with mark=o. Its hard to tell when you dont provide data samples.

Comment: Sorry! I'll add a snippet of code to the original post similar to what I'm working with. Please let me know if there's a different way to display it that works better, I'm new to this site so unfamiliar with giving examples

Comment: I would say that you could plot the values using the `date` column as the x-axis, but there is no numerical values in your data.. So, what exactly do you want to appear in each user's timeline?

Comment: I would like to get a final product that resembles this: https://imgur.com/U5XwZyc

Comment: Sorry is there a way to add a new row to comments? My goal is to be able to select a person and then display a timeline like in the image above, which just shows the events they had happen on each of the given dates

Comment: You may take a look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/timeline.html). It looks similar to what you want

Comment: Nice! You are right, that is more like how I intend my product to look. Thank you for linking me